# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" console error appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a console error (`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`) on line 156 on load and I can't figure it out for the life of me. I've provided the line in question and the full context its in below. Also, I added the site link in case it helps. I would appreciate any and all help/advice.

[Site link](http://staging.keebs.com/)

Here is the line in question (156): `if (!$imgs.length) {return $.Deferred.resolve().promise();}`

Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/Ext4TwdP#

```
//*********************************************************
// Let's start, shall we?
//*********************************************************

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

//*********************************************************
// Global variables
//*********************************************************

    // Morphing icons
    var myIcons = new SVGMorpheus('#iconset', {
        duration: 250,
        rotation: 'none'
    });

//*********************************************************
// Turn off all Ajax caching (IE caches $.load)
//*********************************************************

    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

//*********************************************************
// Preloader
//*********************************************************

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

        $('#projects-list, footer p').hide();

        new QueryLoader2(document.querySelector("body"), {
            barColor: "#f30",
            backgroundColor: "#000",
            barHeight: 1,
            minimumTime: 200,
            fadeOutTime: 0,
            onComplete: function() {
                $('.site-overlay').remove();

                $('#masthead').slideDown(100, function(){
                    $('#projects-list, footer p').show().addClass('fadeInUp');
                });

                // Set a timeout because 100ms is too quick
                $(function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#projects-list, footer p').removeClass('fadeInUp');
                    }, 500);
                });
            }
        });
    });

//*********************************************************
// Small features
//*********************************************************

    // Set top margin for #content to always match the height of the top header
    function resize() {
        var headerTop = $('#masthead').outerHeight();
        (headerTop != parseInt($('#content').css('margin-top').slice(0, -2))) ? $('#content').stop().animate({'margin-top': headerTop}, 150) : console.log('');
    }
    resize();
    window.onresize = resize;

    // Hide header when scrolling down and show header when scrolling up
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
       var st = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (st < lastScrollTop || st === 0){
           $('#masthead').removeClass('unpinned');
       } else {
          $('#masthead').addClass('unpinned');
       }
       lastScrollTop = st;
    });

//*********************************************************
// Project hovers
//*********************************************************

    $('#content').on('mouseenter', 'article.project', function(){

        // If loading icon doesn't exist in the DOM...
        if ( !$('.overlay').find('.loading-icon').length) {

            // And if the project wrapper is activated...
            if ( $(this).closest('#main').find('#project-wrapper').hasClass('activated') ) {
                $(this).addClass('hover');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('hover grayscale grayscale-fade');
            }

        // If loading icon exists in the DOM...
        } else {
            $(this).find('.post-link').hide();
        }

        // Dirty fix for 1px white flicker on hover (Chrome)
        var overlayWidth = $('article.project').outerWidth();
        $('.overlay').css({
            marginLeft: -1,
            width: overlayWidth + 2
        });

    }).on('mouseleave', 'article.project', function(){

        // If #project-wrapper is activated...
        if ( $(this).closest('#main').find('#project-wrapper').hasClass('activated') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
            $(this).find('.post-link').show();

        // If #project-wrapper is not activated...
        } else {

            // If loading icon is present...
            if ( $(this).find('.loading-icon').length ) {

                // Only remove the 'hover' class
                $(this).removeClass('hover');

            // If loading icon is not present...
            } else {

                // Remove all classes
                $(this).removeClass('hover grayscale grayscale-fade');
                $(this).find('.post-link').show();
            }
        }
    });

    // Adjust the project titles so they always fit the container nicely
    function adjustTitle() {
        var thumbWidth = $('article.project > img').outerWidth();
        if (thumbWidth <= 220) {
            $('.overlay > h3').addClass('mobile');
        } else {
            $('.overlay > h3').removeClass('mobile');
        }
    }
    $(window).on('resize', adjustTitle);

//*********************************************************
// Projects
//*********************************************************

    (function($) {

        // Function to allow an event to fire after all images are loaded
        $.fn.imagesLoaded = function () {

            $imgs = this.find('img[src!=""]');
            // if there's no images, just return an already resolved promise
            if (!$imgs.length) {return $.Deferred.resolve().promise();}

            // for each image, add a deferred object to the array which resolves when the image is loaded
            var dfds = [];
            $imgs.each(function(){

                var dfd = $.Deferred();
                dfds.push(dfd);
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function(){dfd.resolve();}
                img.src = this.src;

            });

            // return a master promise object which will resolve when all the deferred objects have resolved
            // IE - when all the images are loaded
            return $.when.apply($,dfds);

        }

        // Function for additional styling
        function projectStyles() {

            // Check the first slide input
            $('#slider input:first').attr('checked', 'checked');

            $('#project-wrapper').addClass('activated');

            // Make the articles grey again after activation
            $('article.project').addClass('grayscale grayscale-fade').css('opacity', '0.4');

            // CSS effects
            $('.post-container').addClass('fadeInUp');
            $('.close-button').addClass('fadeInDown');

            // Remove pesky, sticky 'hover' class
            $('article.project').removeClass('hover');
        }

        // Open the project container
        function openProject() {

            var post_id = $(this).data('id'), // data-id attribute for .post-link
                ajaxURL = site.custom_ajax; // Ajax URL localized from functions.php

            // Add a loading icon
            $('<span class="loading-icon"></span>').insertBefore(this);

            // Add the 'active' class to make sure the div stays dark while loading
            $(this).closest('article.project').addClass('active');

            // Make all the articles grey when an article is clicked
            $('article.project').addClass('grayscale grayscale-fade').css('opacity', '0.4');

            // Remove the corner ribbon
            $('article').removeClass('current');
            $('.corner-ribbon').remove();

            // Get the response from the Ajax function
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajaxURL,
                context: this,
                data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
                success: function(response) {

                    // Add a corner ribbon to note the current activated project
                    $(this).closest('article.project').removeClass('active').addClass('current');
                    $('<div class="corner-ribbon">Current</div>').prependTo('article.current');

                    // Wait until all images are loaded
                    $('#project-container').html(response).imagesLoaded().then(function() {

                        // Remove the loading icon
                        $('.loading-icon').remove();

                        // If the user has scrolled...
                        if ($(window).scrollTop() !== 0) {

                            // First scroll the page to the top
                            $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop : 0
                            },400, function() {

                                // Make the max-height of the container exact for a smoother transition
                                function matchContainerHeight() {
                                    var containerHeight = $('#project-container').outerHeight();
                                    $('#project-wrapper.activated').css('max-height', containerHeight);
                                }
                                setTimeout(matchContainerHeight, 100);
                                $(window).on('resize', matchContainerHeight);

                                projectStyles();

                            });

                        // If the user has not scrolled...
                        } else {

                            // Make the max-height of the container exact for a smoother transition
                            function matchContainerHeight() {
                                var containerHeight = $('#project-container').outerHeight();
                                $('#project-wrapper.activated').css('max-height', containerHeight);
                            }
                            setTimeout(matchContainerHeight, 100);
                            $(window).on('resize', matchContainerHeight);

                            projectStyles();

                        }

                        return false;
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        // User event
        $('#content').on('click', '.post-link', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var projectTitle = $(this).data('title'), // data-title attribute for .post-link
                projectSlug = $(this).data('slug') // data-slug attribute for .post-link

            // Calls openProject() in context of 'this' (.post-link)
            openProject.call(this);

            $('head').find('title').text(projectTitle + ' | Keebs');
        });

    })(jQuery);

//*********************************************************
// Close button
//*********************************************************

    (function($) {

        // Close the project container
        function closeProject() {

            // Remove classes
            $(this).removeClass('fadeInDown');
            $('#project-wrapper').removeClass('activated').css('max-height', '');
            $('article.project').removeClass('grayscale grayscale-fade').css('opacity', '1');
            $('.post-container').removeClass('fadeInUp');
            $('article').removeClass('current');

            // Remove the corner ribbon since no projects are currently activated
            $('.corner-ribbon').remove();

            // Set the height of the project wrapper back to 0
            $('body.single #project-wrapper').css('max-height', 0);

            // Change the title of the document
            $('head').find('title').text(site.title);
        }

        // User event
        $('#content').on('click', '.close-button', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            closeProject();
        });

    })(jQuery);

//*********************************************************
// Home button
//*********************************************************

    (function($) {

        // Load the Home page
        function loadHome() {
            var contactButton = $('#contact-button');

            $('#content').fadeOut(50, function() {
                $('<span class="loading-icon page-loading-icon"></span>').insertBefore('#content');
            }).load(site.url + '/ #primary', function() {
                $('.page-loading-icon').remove();
                $(this).fadeIn(50);
                $('body').removeClass('contact');
                $('#contact-info, #clients').removeClass('fadeInUp');
                $('#projects-list').addClass('fadeInUp');
                $('body.single #project-wrapper').css('max-height', 0);
            });

            // Change the Projects button to 'Contact'
            if ($('body').hasClass('contact')) {
                $(contactButton).removeClass('project-button').addClass('contact-button').attr('data-title', 'Get in touch').css('width', '96px').text('Get in touch').shuffleLetters();
                myIcons.to('mail');
            }

            // Change the title of the document
            $('head').find('title').text(site.title);
        }

        // User event
        $('.site-title a').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Prevent accidental double clicks
            if (!$(this).data('isClicked')) {
                var link = $(this);

                loadHome();

                link.data('isClicked', true);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    link.removeData('isClicked')
                }, 1000);
            }
        });

    })(jQuery);

//*********************************************************
// Contact button
//*********************************************************

    (function($) {

        var contactButton = $('#contact-button');

        // Load the Contact page
        function loadContact() {
            $('#content').fadeOut(50, function() {
                $('<span class="loading-icon page-loading-icon"></span>').insertBefore('#content');
            }).load(site.url + '/contact/ #contact-keebs', function() {
                $('.page-loading-icon').remove();
                $(this).fadeIn(50);
                $('body').addClass('contact');
                $('#projects-list').removeClass('fadeInUp');
                $('#contact-info, #clients').addClass('fadeInUp');
            });

            // Change the Contact button to 'Projects'
            $(contactButton).removeClass('contact-button').addClass('project-button').attr('data-title', 'Projects').css('width', '71px').text('Projects').shuffleLetters();
            myIcons.to('work');

            // Change the title of the document
            $('head').find('title').text('Contact | Keebs');
        }

        // Load the Projects page
        function loadProjects() {
            $('#content').fadeOut(50, function() {
                $('<span class="loading-icon page-loading-icon"></span>').insertBefore('#content');
            }).load(site.url + '/ #primary', function() {
                $('.page-loading-icon').remove();
                $(this).fadeIn(50);
                $('body').removeClass('contact');
                $('#contact-info, #clients').removeClass('fadeInUp');
                $('#projects-list').addClass('fadeInUp');
                $('body.single #project-wrapper').css('max-height', 0);
            });

            // Change the Projects button to 'Contact'
            $(contactButton).removeClass('project-button').addClass('contact-button').attr('data-title', 'Get in touch').css('width', '96px').text('Get in touch').shuffleLetters();
            myIcons.to('mail');

            // Change the title of the document
            $('head').find('title').text(site.title);
        }

        // User event
        $('#mail-wrap').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Prevent accidental double clicks
            if (!$(this).data('isClicked')) {
                var link = $(this);

                if (!contactButton.hasClass('project-button')) {

                    loadContact();

                } else {

                    loadProjects();

                }

                link.data('isClicked', true);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    link.removeData('isClicked')
                }, 500);
            }
        });

    })(jQuery);

//*********************************************************
// Single template
//*********************************************************

    // Check the first slide input
    $('body.single #slider input:first').attr('checked', 'checked');

    // Set the height of the project container
    $('body.single #project-container').imagesLoaded().then(function() {
        var containerHeight = $('#project-container').outerHeight();

        $('body.single #project-wrapper').css('max-height', containerHeight);
    });

    // Make the projects list grayscale if the project wrapper is activated
    if ( $('body.single #project-wrapper').hasClass('activated') ) {
        $('article.project').addClass('grayscale grayscale-fade').css('opacity', '0.4');
    }

//*********************************************************
// Shuffle Letters by Martin Angelov
//*********************************************************

    (function($){

        $.fn.shuffleLetters = function(prop){

            var options = $.extend({
                "step"      : 8,            // How many times should the letters be changed
                "fps"       : 60,           // Frames Per Second
                "text"      : "",           // Use this text instead of the contents
                "callback"  : function(){}  // Run once the animation is complete
            },prop)

            return this.each(function(){

                var el = $(this),
                    str = "";


                // Preventing parallel animations using a flag;

                if(el.data('animated')){
                    return true;
                }

                el.data('animated',true);


                if(options.text) {
                    str = options.text.split('');
                }
                else {
                    str = el.text().split('');
                }

                // The types array holds the type for each character;
                // Letters holds the positions of non-space characters;

                var types = [],
                    letters = [];

                // Looping through all the chars of the string

                for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){

                    var ch = str[i];

                    if(ch == " "){
                        types[i] = "space";
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if(/[a-z]/.test(ch)){
                        types[i] = "lowerLetter";
                    }
                    else if(/[A-Z]/.test(ch)){
                        types[i] = "upperLetter";
                    }
                    else {
                        types[i] = "symbol";
                    }

                    letters.push(i);
                }

                el.html("");

                // Self executing named function expression:

                (function shuffle(start){

                    // This code is run options.fps times per second
                    // and updates the contents of the page element

                    var i,
                        len = letters.length,
                        strCopy = str.slice(0); // Fresh copy of the string

                    if(start>len){

                        // The animation is complete. Updating the
                        // flag and triggering the callback;

                        el.data('animated',false);
                        options.callback(el);
                        return;
                    }

                    // All the work gets done here
                    for(i=Math.max(start,0); i < len; i++){

                        // The start argument and options.step limit
                        // the characters we will be working on at once

                        if( i < start+options.step){
                            // Generate a random character at thsi position
                            strCopy[letters[i]] = randomChar(types[letters[i]]);
                        }
                        else {
                            strCopy[letters[i]] = "";
                        }
                    }

                    el.text(strCopy.join(""));

                    setTimeout(function(){

                        shuffle(start+1);

                    },1000/options.fps);

                })(-options.step);


            });
        };

        function randomChar(type){
            var pool = "";

            if (type == "lowerLetter"){
                pool = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            }
            else if (type == "upperLetter"){
                pool = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            }
            else if (type == "symbol"){
                pool = ",.?/\\(^)![]{}*&^%$#'\"";
            }

            var arr = pool.split('');
            return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
        }

    })(jQuery);

//*********************************************************
// iPad fix for slider
//*********************************************************

    var iPadLabels = function () {
        function fix() {
            var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label'),
                target_id,
                el;
            for (var i = 0; labels[i]; i++) {
                if (labels[i].getAttribute('for')) {
                    labels[i].onclick = labelClick;
                }
            }
        }
        function labelClick() {
            el = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('for'));
            if (['radio', 'checkbox'].indexOf(el.getAttribute('type')) != -1) {
                el.setAttribute('selected', !el.getAttribute('selected'));
            } else {
                el.focus();
            }
        }
        return {
            fix: fix
        }
    }();

    window.onload = function () {

        iPadLabels.fix();

    }

//*********************************************************
// Annnd, we're done!
//*********************************************************

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple problems with this.

1) I didn't declare the `imgs` variable.

2) I didn't include the `()` after `$.Deferred`.

So here's the updated code block:

```
    // Function to allow an event to fire after all images are loaded
    $.fn.imagesLoaded = function () {

        var imgs = this.find('img[src!=""]');

        // If there are no images, just return an already resolved promise
        if (!imgs.length) {
            return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
        }

        // For each image, add a deferred object to the array which resolves when the image is loaded
        var dfds = [];
        imgs.each(function(){

            var dfd = $.Deferred();
            dfds.push(dfd);
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){dfd.resolve();};
            img.src = this.src;

        });

        // Return a master promise object which will resolve when all the deferred objects have resolved
        // IE - when all the images are loaded
        return $.when.apply($, dfds);

    };
```